# Changing Size of Image in CSS

Tags: html, css, image, background

I have HTML and don't have much control over it, but I have full control over the CSS. One tag is an image tag:

```
<img src="photo.jpg" alt="" />
```

I'd like to control the size of this image so that it fits a certain size, like 300px x 200px. I want to keep the proportions, fill my area, but cut off any excess, as it would if I were to do a background "cover"

Like this:

[like this http://cdn.onextrapixel.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/cover-contain.jpg](http://cdn.onextrapixel.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/cover-contain.jpg).

Is there any CSS trick to do this? Or any other trick?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `object-fit: cover` and `object-fit: contain` to achieve this.

```css
.cover {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.contain {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  object-fit: contain;
}
```

```html
<img class="cover" src="http://placebear.com/300/200">

<img class="contain" src="http://placebear.com/300/200">
```

...as long as you aren't concerned about IE.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for the clip property.

```
img {
    position: absolute;
    clip: rect(0px,60px,200px,0px);
}
```

Source: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_clip.asp

Comment: Next time can you not post a link but you do it

Comment: Although your answer is 100% correct, it might also become 100% useless 
if that link is moved, changed, merged into another one or the main site 
just disappears... **:-(** Therefore, please [edit] your answer, and copy 
the relevant steps from the link into your answer, thereby guaranteeing 
your answer for 100% of the lifetime of this site! **;-)** You can always 
leave the link in at the bottom of your answer as a source for your 
material...